# Okular not rendering markdown files

Tags: 20.04, okular, markdown

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04, and then Okular. In my previous Ubuntu 18.04 I often used Okular to render markdown files. Now it is not rendering these format. Do I have to install something extra?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to install [additional backend package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/okular-extra-backends/filelist):

```
sudo apt-get install okular-extra-backends
```